# Increase SQL query timeout in a Execute SQL Query (V2) action

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-logic-apps

I think the title says it all. We have an SQL Query (v2) Action as Logic App step that contains a time-consuming query (about 20 minutes) and this leads to a timeout when we are to schedule our Logic App.

Is there a way to increase the SQL timeout of this query either through the SQL command or the connection settings?

Comment: Is improving the SQL Query so that it runs quicker not an option?

Comment: I think the timeout is 3 minutes, so it is unlikely that we could do that big of an improvement. Have you faced this problem, too @Larnu?

Comment: I don't use Azure apps, however, if I had a query that takes 20 minutes I would certainly be looking to improve its performance.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. I am working on that at the same time.

Comment: Can this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/handle-long-running-stored-procedures-sql-connector#timeout-limit-on-stored-procedure-execution) help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Azure Elastic Job Agent` for `Azure SQL Database`, please refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-overview).

[image]

Please note you need to create credential, target group for `Azure Elastic Job Agent`.

Then you can refer to the tutorial：

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/handle-long-running-stored-procedures-sql-connector#job-agent-for-azure-sql-database

Comment: True. I realized that yesterday. Managing the credentials is getting increasingly complicated using Powershell. I guess I need to create another post just for that. But thank you for the answer.